# Should an employee be made to pay for mandatory training in the uk?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, england-and-wales, scotland

I work for an agency in the uk and the zero hour contract staff are charged for yearly mandatory training by the company. Other agencies appear to not ask for payment for the training or take payment and then reimburse staff after their first shift. Is this legal practice to say they need the training to work, not pay them for their time and insist on a substantial amount being paid to the employer to provide the training?

Comment: "Should" is not a law question. "Can" is. I suggest an edit to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is mandatory training, then it is work, and you need to be paid for it.

As a principle, no decent company will ever ask you to pay to work for them. So this agency asking you is not a decent company.

Comment: As a matter of law, any company requiring you to do something for them must pay minimum wage, no matter whether they call it "training" or "work".